# "Keyword Not Supported 'Port'"

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Still quite new to programming and trying to get my head around hooking a project up to a database. I've created a database using XAMPP/phpmyAdmin and have successfully connected it to my Windows Forms app with the following code:

```
const string connectInfo = @"data source = localhost; Port = 3307; username = 'root'; password = ''; database = caesar_cypher;";
public static void AttemptLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
               
                var connect = new MySqlConnection(connectInfo);
                var LoginCommand = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM login WHERE userName = '{username}' AND password = '{password}';", connect);
                MySqlDataReader reader;
                connect.Open();
                reader = LoginCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                { count += 1; }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Log in successful");
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password - access denied.");
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                connect.Close();
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    var form2 = new CypherForm();
                    form2.Activate();
                    form2.Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This (above) code works perfectly fine, but would be vulnerable to SQL Injection. So I followed and modified my code as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) Microsoft Docs page which covers the `SqlCommand.Prepare()` method.
Now when I run my code I get the following exception:

> Keyword not supported 'port'

Here is the new code:

```
const string connectInfo = @"data source = localhost; Port = 3307; username = 'root'; password = ''; database = caesar_cypher;";
public static bool AttemptSecureLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectInfo))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var loginCommand = new SqlCommand(null, connection)
                    {
                        CommandText =
                        "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userName = @uName AND password = @pWord"
                    };
                    var uNameParam = new SqlParameter("@uName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
                    var pWordParam = new SqlParameter("@pWord", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
                    uNameParam.Value = username;
                    pWordParam.Value = password;
                    loginCommand.Parameters.Add(uNameParam);
                    loginCommand.Parameters.Add(pWordParam);
                    loginCommand.Prepare();
                    loginCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    SqlDataReader reader = loginCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    int count = 0;
                    while(reader.Read())
                    { count += 1; }
                    if(count == 1) { 
                        MessageBox.Show("Log in successful!");
                        var cypherForm = new CypherForm();
                        cypherForm.Activate();
                        cypherForm.Show();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(count > 1) { 
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username/password.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else { 
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username/password.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
```

I've found a few similar posts on here but really can't understand what the problem is, can anyone help?

Ta

Comment: Try to change the connection string. Use different parameters. I think  `Server=localhost:3307;uid=root;database=caesar_cypher;` would be correct The parameter `pwd=;` for the empty passwort is not needed I think. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html for more information.

Comment: You are mixing code for mysql and for ms sql server. The 2nd example from the microsoft documentation is for ms sql server, as it says so on the page you linked.